# Site Speed Page Timings Distribution APV v4

Tags: google-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to pull the Site Speed Page Timings - Histogram Distribution from the Goolge API?  I'm trying to use the API to recreate the image below.

[image]

[Historgram Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAVhH.png)

Comment: Cant tell you what you can rip out of it https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/getting-started https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user_timings

Comment: Thanks.  I can see how I can get the average page load time between a couple of dates, but there doesn't seem to be a way to have a dimension over page load time.

Comment: From what I can tell you can't, unfortunately. The only options I can think of would be hit-level access via BigQuery for Premium customers, or a custom dimension with some kind of hit ID. Nothing out of the box.